# Ruby on Rails - are scopes considered as a violation of SRP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, rails-activerecord

I'm currently studying some best practices and ways to better encapsulate my code from CodeSchool (Rails 4 Patterns).

I ran across the use of "Model Decorators", where you move view specific logic to non Active Record Models that serve all the view related logic of your model(formatting etc.). This also coincides with the Single Responsibility Principle.

Given the above as the premise, are Rails `scope` considered as a violation to the SRP if used only to query reports?

for example

```
class Sales < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sales_per_day, -> { group(:sale_date).sum(:total_sale) }
end
```

Please ignore whatever seems wrong with the example since its just an example of a report.
Is that scope considered as a violation of the SRP that can be moved to a decorator model, a decorator model that handles reports maybe? Or are scopes never going to violate SRP no matter what the case.

Edit: Rephrased question and example to fit my actual question.

Comment: [`scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) is a method in Rails implementation of active rectord. How in the hell you could even imagine it being part of "view logic"?!

Comment: I am aware of it being a method in active record. I am also aware that part of the use case of scope is so that you don't have to build the query anymore on the controller.
 
Since that is the case I am referring to, I was asking if scopes used in such a manner still comply with the SRP or not. How can I imagine that'

Comment: rephrased the question. Is that any better now?

Comment: Yes, it seems clearer. Though I must note, that active record by its very definition violates SRP, since it contains both domain logic and deals with persistence `=/`

Answer (score 4):

No. scopes are not view specific. They are just query builders. The data so fetched can be consumed in many ways, such as `batch processing`, `api's`... etc., which are not necessarily views.

Comment: ok, so scopes are not a violation of SRP? Or am I just thinking too much about what falls under SRP